# How do I reference an input in Angular 4?

Tags: angular

I have the following task that I want to accomplish: users will type on an input element and divs will appear bellow the input with related results. When some div is selected its text is assigned to the input. It's a typical autocomplete functionality.

```
|celio    | -> this is the input                           |celio mendez|
<celio batista> -> div            after selecting the div
<celio mendez> -> div
```

My template:

```
<input id="tbPlaceholder" (click)="search($event.target.value)" />

<div *ngFor="let address of data">
<div  (click)="selectAdress($event.target.innerText)"> {{ address.street}}</div>
```

In my code, I want to reference the input with id of tbPlaceholder so I can set it to the text of the selected div. The problem is that I don' t know how to reference the tbPlaceholder

```
  selectAdress(address: String) : void 
 {
   //how to reference tbPlaceholder?
 }
```

Comment: Read the angular documentation about forms. Use ngModel (i.e. 2-way binding), or a reactive form (i.e. FormControl). You don't need to reference the input. Only to change the text, in the model, which the input is bound to. Same for $event.target.innerText. Don't use the DOM. Use your model, and thus replace that by `selectAddress(address)`.

Answer (score 0):

Some libraries allow that, such as [Angular Material and its autocomplete](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview). But maybe you can't use it, so here it goes :

First, you have your data :

```
data = ['result 1', 'result 2', 'result 3'];
```

And you have your form item :

```
autocompleteQuery: string;
```

Now, my solution for you is to use a pipe, if you know how to use it, here it goes :

```
transform(results: string[], query: string): string[] {
  return query ? 
    results.filter(r => r.toUpperCase().includes(query.toUpperCase())) :
    results;
}
```

This pipe will return filtered results if your query exists, or all results if the query is empty.

Now that you have your pipe, you will have to display the results in your HTML :

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="autocompleteQuery" />
<ng-container *ngIf="autocompleteQuery">
  <div *ngFor="let d of data | myFilteringPipe:autocompleteQuery">{{d}}</div>
</ng-container>
```

And now, this should work.